# Пустое имя файла в TinyMCE, если файл был назван в отличном от латинского алфавите

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, tinymce

При загрузке картинок в *TinyMCE* с именами, отличными от латиницы, в окне загрузки на сервер автоматически устанавливает имя, типа `".расширение"`. То-есть имя пустое, будто бы его что то чистит, может не проходит проверку на регулярку, как вариант. Расширение файла все проходит и остается. При переименовании файла во всплывающем окне, при отправке непосредственно на сервер повторно кириллица исчезает.

Как исправить или сделать замену кириллицы на латиницу?

Какая функция за это отвечает и где она лежит?

Как настроить отсечку данных в *TinyMCE*, для подобных запросов?

Answer (score -1):

смотри проблему в модуле который грузит картинку на сервер(где-то в модулях tinymce), в конфигурации посмотри что за кнопка для загрузки. так найдёшь модуль